# Gitlab CI: why do I get an error when I try to define the pages stage?

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, create-react-app

I'm trying to publish a create-react-app on Gitlab, using its CI.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - pages

build:
  image: node:16
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/

pages:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none        # Do not clone git repo
  script:
    - mv build public         
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public  
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

But unfortunately I get this error:

`This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: pages job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, build, pages, .post.`

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your stages.

You have:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - pages
```

but define:

```yaml
pages:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
```

The stage needs to match:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy <-------
```

Comment: Thanks I missed that! I'm not sure what's the point of the key of the section (pages in my case). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @heapOverflow the key is just to give a custom name you can see in your pipeline. but for pages, it needs to be named "pages" in order for GitLab to see it as a pages step.